# c++ how to initialize global const variables sequentially

Tags: c++, global-variables

I have a problem with initializing global const variables:

```
int a;
const int b = a * a;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    a = std::stoi(argv[1]);
    ...
}
```

I would like to pass values to `a` and `b` in the runtime. However, the above code does not work for `b`. What should I do then? Thanks!!!

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Long answer depends on why you think you need that, because there are multiple ways you could change your code to have something similar enough.

Comment: snarky answer: If you dont use globals variables, the problem does not exist

Comment: I second Yksisarvinen, there are very little good reasons to make something a global variable and without more context we cannot tell you how to solve your actual problem. See also [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: `const auto b = [](){ return a * a; };` with `b()` usage instead of `b`.

Comment: @Jarod42 but then b is a lambda and not a "real" int anymore, isn't it?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX: indeed, We can also use regular function instead `int b(){ return a * a; }`. those functor are generally better to keep relation synchronized.

Answer (score 2):

You can't and it's a real issue when using globals, which is why most large system developers (should) opt out of using the feature.

My favorite approach:

```
int get_global_a(int initial_value=0) {
  static int a = initial_value;
  return a;
}

int get_global_b(int a_value=0) {
  static int b = a_value * a_value;
  return b;
}

/* Make sure this is the first line you execute in your program, but not before main! */
void initialize_all_globals(/* all necessary params */) {
    int a = std::stoi(argv[1]);
    get_global_a(a);
    get_global_b(get_global_a());
}
```

Comment: warning - if your globals have destructors, the order they're called in is still not guaranteed, so in my opinion `static` should be avoided for classes.

Comment: The order of the destructors is guaranteed (to be the reverse of the order of construction). What is still a very subtle issue is that if destructor of global `a` depends on global `b`, without the  constructor of `a` depending on `b`, the guaranteed order of destruction won't necessarily satisfy that dependency. This can be avoided by using dynamic storage and intentional leakage of globals.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize it with a static int like this at runtime. Later changes to the variable lead to a compile error:

```
#include <iostream>

static int hidden_b;
const int& b(hidden_b);

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
    int a = std::stoi(argv[1]);
    hidden_b = a*a;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    //b = 3; // compile error

    // problems arise, if you change the hidden variable
    /*hidden_b = 3;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;*/
}
```